# Can the Grothendieck ring of varities over a field $k$ be defined for non separated schemes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

The Grothendieck ring of varieties over a field $k$ is the abelian group generated by isomorphim classes $[X]$ of separated, reduced $k$-schemes $X$ of finite type with the relation

$[X]=[Y] + [X\setminus Y]$

for any $Y \subset X$ a closed immersion and with the product structure given by

$[X\times Y]= [X]\cdot[Y]$.

My question is related to the condition of separateness. Why do we need the schemes to be separated? I have been searching in different papers and notes and I couldn't find anything about it. Could the Grothendieck ring be extended to non separated schemes?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25122/are-schemes-that-have-enough-locally-frees-necessarily-separated for instance. Of course, you can define the grothendieck group without the condition of separatedness. I think noetherian (or just locally noetherian) should be enough; see Definition 1.4 in https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/MasterJavanpeykar.pdf (I dont recommend you read that text too thoroughly...)

Comment: Thank you for both comments. Yes, the question is about the Grothendieck ring, defined as isomorphims classes of varieties modulo some relations. I should have written the definition in the post, I will edit it so that it is clearer.

Comment: Sorry  I misread the question.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but let me note that schemes need not be reduced neither. If you apply the relation $[X]=[Y]+[X-Y]$ to the inclusion $X_{red} \hookrightarrow X$, them you get $[X]=[X_{red}]$ since the underlying topological space of $X-X_{red}$ is empty. So you can erase "reduced" in your definition of the Grothendieck ring and you get the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the setup of the question correctly, the answer is yes. Using non separated schemes makes no difference.

This is explained [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.4372v1.pdf).

In brief, whether you do the Grothendieck ring of "integral, finite type, separated" or "finite type" or even "finite type algebraic spaces" it's the same. When you pass to stacks it's a whole other mess of course.